# How to install and enable a default and admin theme in a Drupal 8 install profile with just YML (without using hook_install() or a .profile file)?

Tags: configuration, installation-profiles

I want to avoid using `hook_install()` so I can [install from configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2897299).

I'd like my install profile to use `seven` for the admin theme, and my custom theme `rutherford` for the default/main frontend theme.

The annotated `*.info.yml` [example on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/distributions/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile#s-infoyml-file) suggests that putting the following will install my themes:

```
# List any themes that should be installed as part of the profile installation.
# Note that this will not set any theme as the default theme.
themes:
  - rutherford
  - seven
```

My understanding of CMI is that I can then create a file called `www/profiles/rocket/config/optional/system.theme.yml` and put this in it to enable my themes:

```
admin: seven
default: rutherford
```

However none of this seems to work? My themes are found, but not installed *or* enabled:

[image: The Drupal themes interface showing Rutherford and Seven as listed but not installed and not enabled]

Edit:

I've just noticed that the themes are set as default and admin, they're just not installed:

[image: Rutherford is listed with (default theme) next to it, and Seven wigth (administration theme) but neither are installed]

Comment: I noticed that Lightning [does this with a .profile file](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/blob/8.x-4.x/lightning.profile#L77) but I'd rather keep everything in config if possible, so that it's easier for colleagues (and future me) to find where different config settings are set.

Comment: You can't be far off, that's exactly the same method the "standard" profile uses. The only difference is system.theme.yml is located in "config/install", not "config/optional" in core. Maybe that's the smoking gun

Comment: @Clive Unfortunately I have the same problem if I put the theme config in `www/profiles/rocket/config/install/system.theme.yml`. I've based my profile off Standard but it seems to behave differently, for example copying the `block.block.seven_breadcrumbs` from `www/core/profiles/standard/config/install/block.block.seven_breadcrumbs.yml` and putting it in my profile's `config/install` directory gives me a UnmetDependencyException without fail, whereas Standard seems to get away with it somehow!

Comment: Just updated my post to show that the themes are listed as being set as the default and admin themes, they just don't seem to be installed.

Comment: Yeah I just checked some of my profiles, I'm using the theme installer manually in `hook_install` to get my themes installed too. Can't remember why, but I definitely would've tried to do it config first (my thought process is very similar to yours). Maybe there's a bug

Comment: Interestingly the `demo_umami` profile seems to get away with using the `www/core/profiles/demo_umami/demo_umami.info.yml` file. I noticed it has the `umami` theme inside the profile instead of in `www/themes/custom`, so I might give that a try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ‍♂️. Trying to install my `rutherford` theme via the web UI gave a `The rutherford theme was not found.` error message, so it seemed the theme was at fault, not the profile.

I inspected my theme's info file and realised it had a dependency which was not being met. Commenting out the dependency got everything working again!

It's a shame that the `php www/core/scripts/drupal quick-start rocket` did not give me any errors about this unmet theme dependency, otherwise I would have saved about six hours of trying various different configuration approaches! Ah well, ce la Drupal!